# Dimensions change when Ghostscript converts PS to PNG

Tags: png, ghostscript, bounding-box

I use the following minimal PostScript file:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 100 100
0 0 moveto 100 100 rlineto stroke
showpage
```

This draws a line from (0,0) to (100,100) in a 100x100 box.

I then convert this file minimal.ps to a PNG with this command line, borrowed from [GhostScript's documentation](https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm#PNG):

```
gs -sDEVICE=pngmono -o minimal.png minimal.ps
```

With GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3 (current Debian stable) and 9.27 (oldstable) the resulting PNG file has the following dimensions:

```
> identify minimal.png 
minimal.png PNG 612x792 612x792+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 2994B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Both width and height extend far beyond the original BoundingBox, and they are not even equal.

The PNG's dimensions are the same if the output device is pnggray, pngalpha, etc.

The dimensions are also the same if, in the PostScript code, 100 is replaced by 10 or by 10000.

**How can I tell GhostScript to create a PNG file whose dimensions automatically fit the PostScript file's BoundingBox?**

Comment: The BoundingBox in your PostScript program is a **comment** and therefore has no effect. If you want to set the media size then you need to take action to do so. You can do this in PostScript by using the setpagedevice operator. Or you can do so from the command line using -sPAPERSIZE, -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS/-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS, -g and possibly the -dFIXEDMEDIA switch. In the absence of any of these Ghostscript uses its default media size which will be either A4 or US Letter. Or make your program DSC-compliant and use DSC processing, or make it an EPS and use -dEPSCrop.

Comment: OK, adding the line `<< /PageSize [100 100] >> setpagedevice` does the trick. Thanks. I do wonder though why the `%%BoundingBox` line is not treated as a structuring comment. It is used by `gv` for instance and I seem to recall that it was also used by AFPL GhostScript.

Comment: Comments are comments, by default the interpreter ignores comments (as it is supposed to). If the file is DSC-compliant you can use the DSC processing hooks in Ghostscrpt to process the comments. To the best of my knowledge Ghostscript itself has never processed DSC comments without extra work but my memory is hazy and in any event only covers the last 14 years, Ghostscript stopped being AFPL (in favour of GPL and then AGPL) quite a long time ago. GhostView uses the DSC comment processing, it's possible gv does too.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how current GhostScript regards comments.